# Unity 5.6: How to import external .txt files

Tags: unity-game-engine, text, import

Using Unity 5.6 here (I know, outdated **=-(**). How do I import a text file from outside the Assets folder? When I ask that, I do not mean through the Editor. It is going to be input entered by the user (*my own custom modding system*). I need to programmatically import the contents of the text file into a string variable.
Can anyone teach me how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with just doing something like

```
 string pathToFile = @"C:\somepath\sometextfile.txt";
 string textFromFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(pathToFile);
```

is that on many OS (e.g. Android, iOS,  HoloLens) applications run in a sandbox with very limited access to the OSs' file system (if not explicitly granting).

So in Unity basically that is what the [`Application.persitentDataPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html) is for. It can be accessed by both, the application and the OS (for example for changing a text file later).

To ease things up I usually would do this

```c#
    private static string DataPath
    {
        get
        {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
            return Application.streamingAssetsPath;
#else
            return Application.persistentDataPath;
#endif
        }
    }
```

This simply uses the folder `<yourUnityProject>/Assets/StreamingAssets` while you are in the Editor in order to not `bload` data into your PC's persistent data path while testing.

Later in a build it uses the App specific folder (depending on you OS - see link above).

---

In the Editor create the folder `Assets/StreamingAssets` and place your `.txt` file there.

You can read using

```c#
public static string ReadFromFile(string fileName)
{
    var filePath = Path.Combine(DataPath, fileName);

    //only needed if you choose option 1 in the next step
    var copyFile = false;

    // Check if file exists
    if (!File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        // if the file does not exist (especially later in a build) 
        // you have multiple options
        // I would decide between the following three

        // OPTION 1
        // read in the text from streaming assets instead 
        // the first time and create a new file from that content
        filePath = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, fileName);
        copyFile = true;
        // Note: as fallback if this also does not exist use one of the other two options


        // OPTION 2
        // Alternatively you might rather want to instead create 
        // the file with some default content and change it later
        WriteToFile(fileName, "some default content");

        // OPTION 3
        // simply throw an error an do nothing
        Debug.LogErrorFormat("Error reading {0}\nFile does not exist!", filePath);
        return null;
    }

    // Read in data from file
    using (var file = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
    {
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(file, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            //this check is only needed for option 1
            // otherwise only use the else part
            if(copyFile)
            {
                var output = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                WriteToFile(fileName, output);
                return output;
            } 
            else
            {
                return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and write using

```c#
public static void WriteToFile(string fileName, string content)
{
    var filePath = Path.Combine(DataPath, fileName);

    // Create file or overwrite if exists
    using (var file = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write))
    {
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(file, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            writer.Write(content);
        }
    }

    Debug.LogFormat("Written to {0}", filePath);
}
```

---

You can put above code simply in a `public static class` e.g. somthing like

```c#
public static class File
{
    //...
}
```

than you can call it later from everywhere by simply using

```c#
File.ReadFromFile("MyFile.txt");
```

without having to reference.

Comment: Thank you @derHugo, it worked! I was so confused on how to do this, because everyone told me to do what SwiftingDuster did.

Comment: @CheyMoore glad to help! There are certainly multiple ways for how to do that but I've found this one the most readable and reliable

Answer (score 1):

You can read a text file with:

```
string pathToFile = @"C:\somepath\sometextfile.txt";
string textFromFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(pathToFile);

// Use the data
```

Comment: Sorry, @SwiftingDuster, that does not work in Unity, or at least involving my problem.

Comment: Why wouldn't it work? Maybe you can be more specific on your problem?

Comment: @SwiftingDuster this might work in the Editor (or not I don't know why it shouldn't right now) but in a Build it depends how the OS works. On most OS the applications run in a sandbox that has very limitted access (except you explicitely allow them) to the OS's filesystem (e.g. Android, iOS, HoloLens ...). You should rather use the [Persistent Data Path](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html) (also see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53184697/7111561))